# Start playing the video after 50% downloaded

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to know how much resource(video file in my case) has been downloaded(in terms of % size) through javascript ?

I need to start playing an HTML5 video after it has been 50% downloaded ? How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AJAXVideoPlayer.aspx

And if you need it in flash you can try this http://www.flashrealtime.com/play-currently-downloading-video-in-air-filestream-and-